# My coloured div shows up in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, html, colors

I have a empty div on my page that is centred and is filled with only a colour.  When coding I am using firefox as my test browser.  I had issues getting the div to appear and when I checked it in chrome it appeared no problem. Now it only appears in chrome.  Im not sure if it is a simple extension that needs to be used or my code is wrong.  My code and css is posted below.  Any advise helps as this is getting a tad frustrating.

```
div.slider {
    background-color:#78A9AD;
    width: 15vw; 
    height: 25vw;
    clear:left;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top:60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slider" >

</div>
```

Comment: try with `-moz-background-color:#78A9AD;`

Comment: Remove `width: 100%;`

Comment: Check your Firefox version ... you are using `vw` units http://caniuse.com/viewport-units ... works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/2kC23/

Comment: the above code looks fine in my FF, v. 25.0.1 (even with vw units)

Comment: Replace your code with this `.slider { background: #78A9AD; position: absolute; width: 15vw; height: 25vw; top: 50%; left: 0; margin: 60px auto; }` btw viewport units are supported by Firefox.

Comment: It still Doesnt work in firefox